# How to prevent duplicate user assignment to various record of same custom object

Tags: workflow, validation, business-logic

I am having one custom object name as club with custom lookup field with contact object.

Let us assume we have 3 records in my club object(club1,club2 and club3).

When I assigned one member to club1 record , I shouldn't assign the same member to another record either in club2 or club3.

If I try to assign the same member to other club records I should be stopped with an error message.

How this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Lookup can not be unique, you will have to create a new text field(e.g:ContactId__c) and make it **Unique**, that's very important. Then by workflow, you can populate this text field from your custom lookup.

So now that means when you create a new member for the same contact, you will get the following error :
**"Duplicate value on record: 'Record_Name' (Related field: ContactId)**"

Comment: Thanks its working fine. Can I customize this error message "Duplicate value on record: 'Record_Name' (Related field: ContactId)".

Comment: Unfortunately not with this solution. If you want a custom error message, you will need to go for a solution with a trigger which is more expensive as you will need some code and a developer.